# How to consume a web service from a Windows Forms app using .Net3.5

Tags: c#, web-services

I am attempting to consume a web service from within a Windows Forms application, by adding the URL as a Service Reference in Visual Studio. The web service is hosted on a remote (customer) intranet to which I am connected over a VPN connection. I am expecting to call various methods on the web service and use the returned XML data in the Windows Forms application.

When I attempt to add the service reference in Visual Studio by entering the URL and clicking 'Go', I get a 404 error. My questions are:

1. Is there something else I need to do in VS2008 or in code, or is this simply a network or Web service problem?
2. Do I *have* to use WCF in the Windows Forms application to connect to the web service?

Comment: A 404 error will generally indicate that the url is unreachable. Maybe it's simply the wrong url, maybe your VPN is not configured properly / connected, or maybe there is a proxy server that you need to use in someway, it's really a broad range of possible issues. As for the second part of your question, a "web service" is also a pretty generic term. What type of a web service is it? If it's a soap service, then you need a soap client, if it's a plain http rest service, you need a http / rest client, etc.

Comment: It's a REST web service. How do I connect to that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try it in a browser, like this: http://100.100.100.100/service/service.svc

But then, is it a WCF service at all? Is it your service, or some public service, if so, which one?

Also, have you tried connecting to it from a WcfTestClient? That little app is precious!

Comment: WcfTestClient requires a metadataendoint, and this web service doesn't provide one.